# Problem with roslaunch on a local machine

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a robot which is my ros_master and my local machine which is able to to list the nodes and topics and also do rosrun. I have ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP correctly set on both machines. However when I want to start a package on my local machine using roslaunch ( in my case I am trying to launch gmapping) I have problems. My local machine tries to run roscore locally and it gives me errors.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192864/problem-with-roslaunch-on-a-local-machine/) by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently I had set the ROS_HOSTNAME to the name of my ros_master instead of the name of my local machine. So for this to work we need to set the ROS_HOSTNAME to the name of the local machine ( in /etc/hosts) or its IP, set the ROS_IP to the ip of the local machine and ROS_MASTER_URI to the ip of the master.

---

Originally posted by [zeinab](https://answers.ros.org/users/20114/zeinab/) with karma: 88 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0